# Simplifying an expression using .map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Below I have an example active record query using a bunch of `each` iterators

```
user.user_spells.each do |us|
  us.spell.buff_effects.where(stat_effected:'gold').each do |be|
    value = value + be.value
  end
end
```

I would like to use .map to return a list of all the results so I can do it essentially in one line.

I came up with:

```
user.user_spells.map { |us| us.spell.buff_effects.where(stat_effected:stat_effected) }.each do |be|
  value = value + be.value
end
```

However... the `.map` block returns some empty arrays.  Not sure how to write it correctly.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably along these lines, if what you want is the sum of values in the end:

```
value =
  user.user_spells.flat_map do |us|
    us.spell.buff_effects.where(stat_effected:'gold').map(&:value)
  end.reduce(&:+)
```